# Entire network sluggish after virus

Tags: windows, networking, performance, anti-virus

I am almost positive that I got a virus from en.savefrom.net, although both Windows Defender and Avast found nothing.

The Internet has become sluggish for all devices on the network, including PCs, Macs, and Android phones. We don't share files via the network.

The computer on which I got the virus, a Windows 10 machine, is also marginally more sluggish, even though Task manager doesn't show any problems. My mouse pointer is now often accompanied by a loading symbol, which used to happen only rarely. Task manager hangs when opening. My computer isn't too slow other than subtle hints like those.

I want to just reset my OS, but there seem to be indications of the virus somehow infiltrating the rest of the network. How can I know what to do?

Comment: Is it a home network ?

Comment: Yes, and one of the PCs is wired.